# How to replace multiple strings with the same in R

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

I have a string

```
vec = c('blue','red','flower','bee')
```

I want to convert different strings into the same in one line instead of seperately
i.e. i could gsub blue and gsub red to make them both spell 'colour'. How can I do this in one line?

output should be:
'colour','colour','flower','bee'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sub("blue|red", "colour", vec)
```

use "|" (which means the logical `OR` operator) between the words you want to substitute.

Use `sub` to change only the first occurence and `gsub` to change multiple occurences within the same string.

Type `?gsub` into R console for more information.

Comment: will this work if my actual string consists of phrases?

Comment: yes.

Try it with `sentence <- c("my favourite color is blue, red is what i dont like", "flowers are great")` and see the difference between `sub` and `gsub`

Answer (score 4):

Here you do not need to specify the colors to be replaced, it will replace any color that R knows about (returned by `colors()`)

```
> col <- paste0(colors(), collapse = "|")
> gsub(col, "colour", vec)
[1] "colour" "colour" "flower"  "bee"
```

Also, as suggested in the comments (which will obviously only work if the element is the color only, so the `gsub` method seems better suited to your purposes):

```
> vec[vec %in% colors()] <- "coulour"
> vec
[1] "coulour" "coulour" "flower"  "bee"
```