# Remove specific phrases from a string

Tags: r, gsub

I am attempting to utilise R for some basic text analytics.

I have a column containing complex data type. I wish to maintain a separate table that I can use to remove certain phrases from the 1st data column.

I have tried gsubfn but without any success.

For example

```
dirtydata <- c("JOHN COURT","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <-c("COURT","BODY CORPORATE")
```

Why does

```
x <- gsubfn(removefields,"",dirtydata)
```

not work?

Hoping for an output

```
c("JOHN ","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT ")
```

Comment: please include the name of additional loaded packages. but you can try `gsub(paste(removefields, collapse = "|"),"",dirtydata)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple strings with the same in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285480/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-with-the-same-in-r) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645390/r-remove-multiple-text-strings-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below edited code using `base` functions of R

```
dirtydata <- c("JOHN COURT","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <-c("COURT","BODY CORPORATE")
pastedFields = paste0(removefields,collapse = "|")
gsub(pastedFields,"",dirtydata)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it more? I am assuming you are getting output in list format you excepting vector? If so, please put the line of code where you applied it on column of your data

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dirtydata <- c("JOHN COURT","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <-c("COURT | BODY CORPORATE")
x <- gsub(removefields, "", dirtydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

This generalises for whatever you put into `removefields` and strips white spaces around strings to be removed:

```
dirtydata <- c("JOHN COURT","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <- c("COURT","BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <- paste0("\\s+", removefields, "\\s+", collapse = "|")
x <- gsub(removefields, "", dirtydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tm` package

```
dirtydata <- c("JOHN COURT","@PETER","BOB 22","RUPERT BODY CORPORATE")
removefields <-c("COURT","BODY CORPORATE")

library(tm)
removeWords(dirtydata, removefields)

> removeWords(dirtydata, removefields)
[1] "JOHN "   "@PETER"  "BOB 22"  "RUPERT "
```