# Replacing words with spaces within a tibble in R without anti-join

Tags: r, n-gram, stop-words, tibble

I have a tibble of sentences like so:

A tibble: 1,782 x 1

```
Chat
<chr>                                                                                                                                                                    
1 Hi i would like to find out more about the trials
2 Hello I had a guest 
3 Hello my friend overseas right now
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove stopwords like "I", "hello". I already have a list of them and I want to replace these stopwords with a space. I tried using mutate and gsub but it only takes in a regex. Anti join won't work here as I am trying to do bigram/trigram I don't have a single word column to anti-join the stopwords.

Is there a way to replace all these words in each sentences in R?

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285480/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-with-the-same-in-r

Comment: No it's not. How could I use "|" for a list of stopwords that is dynamic.

Comment: Probably something like this : `stopwords <- c("I", " Hello"); gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"), "", df$Chat)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could unnest the tokens, `replace` the 'word' that is found in the 'stop_words' 'word' column with space (`" "`), and `paste` the 'word' after grouping by 'lines'

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
rowid_to_column(df1, 'lines') %>% 
     unnest_tokens(word, Chat) %>% 
     mutate(word = replace(word, word %in% stop_words$word, " ")) %>% 
     group_by(lines) %>% 
     summarise(Chat = paste(word, collapse=' ')) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     select(-lines)
```

NOTE: This replaces the stop words found in 'stop_words' dataset to `" "`  If we need only a custom subset of stop words to be replaced, then create a `vector` of those elements and do the change in the `mutate` step

```
v1 <- c("I", "hello", "Hi")
rowid_to_column(df1, 'lines') %>%
  ...
  ...
  mutate(word = replace(word %in% v1, " ")) %>%
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: why do we have to use rowid_to_column? and what does select(-lines) do? In this case, lines column will be my row id?

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a pattern with "`\\b` stop word `\\b`" and then use `gsub` to replace them with "". Here is an example. Notice that I set `ignore.case = TRUE` to include both lower and upper case, but you may want to adjust that for your needs.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Chat
                  1 'Hi i would like to find out more about the trials'
                  2 'Hello I had a guest' 
                  3 'Hello my friend overseas right now'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat
#                                                Chat
# 1 Hi i would like to find out more about the trials
# 2                               Hello I had a guest
# 3                Hello my friend overseas right now

# A list of stop word
stopword <- c("I", "Hello", "Hi")
# Create the pattern
stopword2 <- paste0("\\b", stopword, "\\b")
stopword3 <- paste(stopword2, collapse = "|")

# View the pattern
stopword3
# [1] "\\bI\\b|\\bHello\\b|\\bHi\\b"

dat$Chat <- gsub(pattern = stopword3, replacement = " ", x = dat$Chat, ignore.case = TRUE)
dat
#                                               Chat
# 1     would like to find out more about the trials
# 2                                      had a guest
# 3                     my friend overseas right now
```

Comment: I tried stopw <- paste0("\\b", stop_words$word, "\\b") %>%                paste(collapse = "|") but it's returning me this error: assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634

Comment: my stopwords list contains quotation not sure if it matters. Things like a's, couldn't, won't.

Comment: @wayneloo Not sure what happened. Please make sure the code works for the small example you provided, then research your real-world data.

Comment: Found out what's wrong. The stopword list I have 1149 number of words. In this method, the number of OR operations in regex for a thousand plus words is too much which cause the error. So this method probably works only for a smaller subset of custom stopwords list.

Comment: @wayneloo Thanks for testing my code. Perhaps akrun's solution will work.